# Как задать значение Х в javaFX при нажатии кнопки с клавиатуры?

Tags: javafx

Вот код, я хочу чтоб клавиша А на клавиатуре запускала действие вместо кнопки btn. Как это сделать? Если можно, напишите код как пример.

```
import java.util.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

public class Dispatcher extends Application {
    GraphicsContext gc ;
    Timer t;
    Button btn;
    int i=1;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    public void start (Stage myStage){
        myStage.setTitle("Game");
        FlowPane rootNode = new FlowPane();
        rootNode.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene myScene = new Scene(rootNode,1000,900);
        myStage.setScene(myScene);
        Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(900,800);
        gc = myCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        final TimerTask animation = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                gc.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                gc.fillRect(0,0,900,800 );
                i++;
                gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
                gc.fillOval(i ,i+1 ,i ,i+1 );
            }
        };
        t = new Timer();
        Button btn = new Button("0");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent ae) {                
                    t.schedule(animation, 0, 10);
            }
        });
        rootNode. getChildren ().addAll(myCanvas, btn);
        myStage.show ( ) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо повесить хендлер на всю Stage, в которой обрабатывать необходимое поведение

```
myStage.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, keyEvent - > {
    if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.A) {
        t.schedule(animation, 0, 10);
    }
});
```

Стоит так же отметить, что если у вас будет какое-нибудь текстовое поле, и  вы будете набирать там текст, который содерджит в себе букву А, то таймер запуститься тоже. Чтобы этого избежать, необходимо смотреть, от какого компонента пришел ивент. Такую проверку позволяет делать `keyEvent.getSource()`

Answer (score 1):

если нужно именно имитировать нажатие кнопки, тогда:

```
myStage.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, keyEvent - > {
    if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.A) {
        btn.fire();
    }
});
```